# When training a Deep learning model on multiple datasets, is it better concatenating all datasets and shuffling it, or train datasets sequentially?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

So lets say that I Have datasets A, B, and C to train a model. My current solution take batches randomly from A, then from B, then from C. I wonder if concatenating all datasets and shuffling so that training would be more random would improve results

Comment: How different from each other are A, B, C?

Comment: Is one of the sets more critical than the others, as far as avoiding false positives/negatives?

Comment: I would say they may be considerable different. For example one or more datasets consisting of real pictures and other consisting of synthetic data (generated on blender) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330797/when-training-a-deep-learning-model-on-multiple-datasets-is-it-better-concatena#comment122540887_69330797), the samples in the datasets are drawn from slightly different "distributions" (e.g., real vs synthetic images). In this case, it is better to randomly sample points from all datasets *for each batch*, rather than going sequentially through the different datasets.